# Escaping hyphen in MySQL query (not using a backtick)

Tags: mysql, quartz-scheduler

We have an existing schema we're trying to fit some quartz tables into, but the tables are named with hyphen in them, so we'd like to use a prefix like "08-Scheduling_QUARTZ_"

Since quartz doesn't wrap any of the queries in back ticks, the prefix doesn't work.

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '08-Scheduling_QUARTZ_TRIGGERS SET TRIGGER_STATE = 'WAITING' WHERE SCHED_NAME' at line 1]]`

Curious if there is **any chance there is some other way to escape the "-" in a mysql query** other than `` around the whole table name?

I've tried

x'-'x

x\-x

x"-"x

x`-`x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must delimit the identifier if it has certain punctuation characters.

In MySQL, the default identifier delimiter is the back-tick.

If you enable the `ANSI` or `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL modes, you can use double-quotes as an identifier delimiter.

If you don't want to use delimiters, you must choose a different convention for prefixing your table names. You could use `_` for example.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html for more details on the characters permitted in identifiers without delimiters.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping there was some magic I could squeeze between.  ;)